# can't remove clone in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form that gives user to add or remove group of html forms, by using jquery I am able to add clone but can't remove added form. Here is my code:

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="form-group"><label>Area/Domain:</label><input type="text" name="domain" class="form-control"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label>Current Level:</label><input type="text" name="cLevel" class="form-control"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label>Annual Goal:</label><input type="text" name="aGoal" class="form-control"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label>Remarks:</label><textarea name="remarks" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

my script is:

```
<div id="clone"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#createClone").click(function(){
$("#parent").clone().appendTo("#clone");
});
});
</script>
<script>
$("#deleteClone").click(function(){
$("#parent").clone().remove("#clone");
});
</script>
<button id="createClone" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Fields</button>
<button id="deleteClone" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Fields</button>
```

Comment: I think you should be doing something like `$('#parent #clone:last').remove();`

Comment: `$('#clone #parent:last').remove();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the `parent` into a class, and then use `$(".parent").remove("#clone .parent:last");`

The reason I change `$(".parent").clone()` into  `$(".parent:first")` is so it only clones 1 `parent` each time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#createClone").click(function() {
    var clone = $(".parent:first").clone();
    $("<h5>clone"+$(".parent").length+"</h5>").insertBefore(clone.find(".form-group:first"))
    clone.appendTo("#clone");
  });
});
$("#deleteClone").click(function() {
  $(".parent").remove("#clone .parent:last");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="form-group"><label>Area/Domain:</label><input type="text" name="domain" class="form-control"></div>
  <div class="form-group"><label>Current Level:</label><input type="text" name="cLevel" class="form-control"></div>
  <div class="form-group"><label>Annual Goal:</label><input type="text" name="aGoal" class="form-control"></div>
  <div class="form-group"><label>Remarks:</label><textarea name="remarks" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea></div>
  <br>
</div>

<div id="clone"></div>
<button id="createClone" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Fields</button>
<button id="deleteClone" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Fields</button>
```

Comment: Can we also give numbers to clone if possible?

Comment: sure we can, but where would you like the number, as a class or ?

Comment: I just want to show that the user created a Added field#1, #2, #3.. when user keeps clicking on...

Comment: @Kanna Still a bit hard to know where you want the added values, but I updated the snippet so you have an idea.

Comment: Hi, the form working fine now. Although I need to insert clone data into database. Anyone of you have any suggestions please?

Comment: @Kanna I would suggest that you create a new question regarding this.